# What is the etiquette for asking a professor I don't know to suggest universities for me?

Tags: etiquette, email

Because of the current political situation, I cannot apply for a PhD in the USA. There is a very remarkable professor on a U.S. university and I want to ask him to suggest for me other universities that are good to be considered.

I want to know your opinion about this.

And, if you agree, how can I state my request?

Comment: I would be very hesitant if someone I did not know asked me my opinion of other universities. I would be happy to answer if it was someone I knew.

Comment: If I am assuming correctly that the professor as well as the universities you are seeking are good in a specific subfield that you are interested in, you should add this to the question

Comment: can you help me in writing my request?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would advise against it.

I don't think most people have in their heads a list of "good universities in my field".  When advising students who they know on where to apply for grad school, they try to recommend schools based on everything they know about the student, their interests, talents, constraints, etc.  For a student who they don't know and have never met, this would be hard to do effectively, and I don't think most people would really be interested in trying.

If you send such an email, I suspect you will either get no response, or a brief "Sorry, I can't help".

Instead, I would suggest that you talk to a faculty member in your field at your own university, someone who knows you well and whose opinion you respect.  They would be a much better source of advice for you.